# Installing process as service directory decision

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, system32

I have a process that is going to run as Windows Service.
I have successfully installed it as Windows Service and everything works.

My question is what are the guide lines for process directory.

On the machine Im going to deploy it, does the setup need to copy the .exe  to Windows/System32 and then install as service ?  Or i can deploy it to C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe and install as service from there.

It is not required for the .exe to be in /Windows/System32/ but is it "Best practice" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You shouldn't install anything to the Windows System folder. That's for operating system code.

You should install to your own application folder within the Program Files folder, and register as a Windows service thereafter.